# When is a k-space locally compact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness

We're looking at the possible cardinal sequences of LCS (locally compact, Hausdorff, [scattered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattered_space)) spaces, which has led us to think about taking a quotient of a locally compact, scattered space.

A k-space (compactly generated Hausdorff space) is [a quotient space of a disjoint union of compact Hausdorff spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space#Definition). Every locally compact Hausdorff space is a k-space, but not every k-space is locally compact. However, every k-space is a quotient of a locally compact Hausdorff space.

1. Is there a general condition for a k-space to be locally compact?
2. What if we assume the space is a quotient of an LCS space?
3. Is there a condition that also guarantees a k-space is an LCS space?

Looking through Engelking and Google I couldn't find anything.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a definition of 'scattered' in your question. Also can you please point to a reference for the assertion that every k-space is a quotient of a disjoint union of compact Hausdorff spaces: is this a characterisation of k-spaces?

Comment: Thank you Peter, I've edited my question to include links to these - the assertion about k-spaces is number 3 in the equivalent characterisations of compact generation.

Comment: This is a very good question, especially if it's not in the usual places one looks. If we get a good answer here, it can also be recorded in the nLab for posterity, since these are not insignificant closure conditions for the categories of spaces involved.

Comment: It seems worth mentioning that in [condensed math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_mathematics) it's an important principle that every compact Hausdorff space is a quotient of a totally disconnected (or even: extremally disconnected) compact Hausdorff space. Since a compact $T_1$ scattered space is the same thing as a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space  containing no perfect set, asking what spaces are quotients of these is a way of putting some more constraints on a space than what one sees in condensed math.

Comment: @Tim I was thinking something similar, though it's a fact *used* in condensed mathematics, not so much a piece *of* condensed mathematics.

Comment: @YCor: I do believe that the standard typesetting is in fact $k$-space, rather than k-space.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I doubt so (like $K$-theory looks clumsy though often used — this also applies to any use of math mode within text). I checked Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space before editing, since they usually have good typing conventions.

Comment: @YCor: We went with the convention from nLab...

Answer (score 5):

$\DeclareMathOperator\colim{colim}\DeclareMathOperator\CS{CS}\DeclareMathOperator\CSN{CSN}$The examples considered in algebraic topology are usually like $\mathbb{R}^\infty=\colim_n\mathbb{R}^n$ or $O(\infty)=\colim_n O(n)$ (the infinite orthogonal group) or infinite-dimensional CW complexes.  These can usually be written as the colimit of locally compact Hausdorff spaces $X_n$ and
closed inclusions $X_n\to X_{n+1}$, where $X_n$ typically has
empty interior in $X_{n+1}$.  In this context, a standard lemma
says that every compact subset $K\subseteq X$ is contained in
some $X_n$ and so has empty interior in $X_{n+1}$ (and therefore
also has empty interior in $X$).  Thus, examples of this type
will never be locally compact.

One could consider the class $\mathcal{C}$ of k-spaces in which every compact set has empty interior, which is a kind of opposite to local compactness.   I think that this class of spaces contains most of the popular examples and has good closure properties.

On the other hand, very many spaces can be written as a quotient of an LCS space.  Indeed, let $\CS(X)$ be the set of continuous maps $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}\to X$ (i.e. pairs consisting of a convergent sequence and its limit).  We can give $\CS(X)$ the discrete topology and the space $\CSN(X)=\CS(X)\times(\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\})$ the product topology.  This makes $\CSN(X)$ into an LCS space, with an evident surjective evaluation map $\epsilon\colon \CSN(X)\to X$.  The space $X$ is said to be *sequential* if $\epsilon$ is a quotient map.  (The definition is usually phrased differently, but easily seen to be equivalent.)  One can check that if $X$ is a k-space and every compact subspace is metrisable then $X$ is sequential.  This covers most examples typically considered in algebraic topology.

My guess is that the space $\beta(\mathbb{N})$ (the Stone–Čech compactification of the naturals) is not a quotient of an LCS space, but I have not checked that.

Comment: The reasoning in the last paragraph works more generally when you replace sequential spaces by [strongly pseudoradial spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4624)

Comment: To amplify @Tyrone 's comment, if you can show that every scattered space is strongly pseudoradial (which seems plausible to me), then you can deduce that a space is a quotient of scattered spaces iff it is strongly pseudoradial. Since a space is pseudoradial iff it is a quotient of a disjoint union of ordinals (which is LCS), this would be mean that a space is a quotient of an LCS space iff it is strongly pseudoradial, iff it is a quotient of a scattered space. This would also mean that every scattered space is a $k$-space.

Comment: @TimCampion If you take the subspace $\mathbb{N}\cup\{p\}$ of $\beta\mathbb{N}$, where $p\in\mathbb{N}^*$ (known as $\Sigma$ in Problem 4M in Gillman and Jerison) then you have a scattered space that is not strongly pseudoradial.

Comment: @KPHart neither is $\mathbb{N}\cup\{p\}$ a k-space.

Comment: Thank you Neil, this is very helpful!

Comment: @Tyrone That more than dashes Tim Campion's hopes.

Answer (score 2):

For first-countable regular spaces (which form an important subclass of LCS-spaces) there exists a simple characterization: a first-countable regular space $X$ is not locally countably compact if and only if $X$ contains a closed subspace, homeomorphic to the subspace $$\mathbb L=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(\tfrac1n,\tfrac1{nm}):n,m\in\mathbb N\}$$ of the Euclidean plane.

This characterization implies that a first-countable paracompact space $X$ is locally compact if and only if $X$ contains no closed subspaces, homeomorphic to $\mathbb L$.

Comment: Thank you Taras!

Comment: Was this (almost) trivial characterization helpful? I hope that you would be rather interested in characterization of LC and LCS-spaces among cosmic $k_\omega$-spaces, which often appear in algebraic topology and topological algebra. A cosmic $k_\omega$ space is locally compact (and scattered) iff it is first-countable (and countable).

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful! I hadn't actually heard of cosmic $k_\omega$-spaces (I've come from more of a set-theoretic topology background rather than algebraic topology), but I will look into these - thank you

Comment: "cosmic" is abbreviation of a "continuous image of a separable metric space". A topological space is cosmic if and only if it has a countable network of the topology, see Section 4 in this survey paper of Gruenhage (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444865809500136).